# how to get max. value for a non linear data

Tags: function, matlab

I am a new Matlab user..so quite unfamilier with most of its power...Actually I need to get the maximum value in a non linear moment curvature curve...I define the theoretical max. and min. curvature values in the program and then divide it in small discrete increments...but the problem is...the max. value sometimes occur in between two increments...so the program misses that one...and it stops before finding the max. value...Please help me...how can I overcome this problem

Comment: How are you calculating the max/min?  Could you post some code?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to approximate the curve, using an interpolation/fitting scheme that depends on the problem and the curve shape, and the known functional form. A spline might be appropriate, or perhaps not.

Once you have a viable approximation that connects the dots so to speak, you minimize/maximize that function. This is an easily solved problem at that point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to solve non linear functions (find minima/maxima)
It uses least squares non linear method and I think is called lsqnonlin(). Find it in optimization toolbox. Also solve() might work. Another option is to use simulated annealing but I don't remember the name of the function.
Sorry I don't supply code. I am answering from iphone